# When does a script element made with Javascript actually load?

Tags: javascript, html

Imagine a simple function:

```
let f = ()=> {
  let myScript=document.createElement("script");
  myScript.src="otherFile.js";
  alert(x);
  x=2;
  alert(x);
}
```

...and otherFile.js looks like this:

```
x=3;
```

Assuming x starts at the value 4, wha alert  will I get 1st when I call `f();`

Comment: Note, that the new script is never executed, you've to insert the newly-created element to the DOM in order to get the script executed.

Comment: Well run it.... what happens?

Comment: You don't append it to the DOM, and it would have to fetch the file from the server so it's certainly not going to interleave with your blocking synchronous calls.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to append it to the DOM:

```
let f = ()=> {
  let myScript=document.createElement("script");
  myScript.src="otherFile.js";
  document.body.append(myScript)
  alert(x);
  x=2;
  alert(x);
}
```

If you want to, you can do a simple in-browser example right now. For that you'll need to either upload a js file to a CDN and add it to src, or take the easier route and just update the innerHTML:

```
let f = ()=> {
  let myScript=document.createElement("script");
  myScript.innerHTML="x=5";
  document.body.append(myScript)
  alert(x);
  x=2;
  alert(x);
}
```

As you can see you get `5` alerted.